# Webdriver - Page Object Model and Maven Cannot find class

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pom.xml

The first my directory look like:

```
+- pom.xml
+- src/
   +- test/
      +- java/
        +- dms.config/
            +- config.java
        +- dms.util/
            +- generatedata.java
        +- dms.pages/
            +- LoginPage.java
        +- dms.testcase/
            +- LoginTest.java
```

My `testng.xml` look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes> 
      <class name="dms.testcase.LoginTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

My POM:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>pl.rsoftstudio</groupId>
  <artifactId>dms</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>dms</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>bintray</name>
    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>


  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.48.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.10</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>

          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.6</version>
             <configuration>

               <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

             </configuration>
           </plugin>      
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

When I try to run my test via Maven I've got:

> [TestNGClassFinder] Warning: Can't link and determine methods of class dms.testcase.LoginTest

When I run my test "Run As" "TestNG Test" is OK.

I use Right click on the project and select Maven > Update Project...

Add LoginTest.class:

```
package dms.testcase;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import dms.config.Main;
import dms.pages.kancelaria.LoginPage;

public class LoginTest extends Main {

    LoginPage lp = new LoginPage();

    @Test
    public void login() throws Exception {
            lp.login();
            lp.password();
            lp.buttonOK();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not configure the `maven-surefire-plugin` to use your specific TestNG suite file. From [the docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html), you need to have the following configuration in your POM:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

As a side-note, you are declaring `junit` also in your POM when you don't use it so it would be best to remove that dependency. Also, your current `testng` dependency should be of scope `test` and not `compile`, like this:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.9.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that output folder for your project should be /target/test-classes.
And your POM should have entry for source as per below:

```
    <testSourceDirectory>src</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>target/test-classes</outputDirectory>
```

Comment: Come on, stop guessing and saying non-sense. `<testSourceDirectory>src</testSourceDirectory>`? Really? It is `src/test/java`, the default and the OP uses it.

Comment: This is how I run my tests using maven

Answer (score 0):

My problem was POM.xml. I changed  and now its look like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>pl.rsoftstudio</groupId>
  <artifactId>dms</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>dms</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.48.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>br.eti.kinoshita</groupId>
      <artifactId>testlink-java-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.8-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> 
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.9.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```